# Suppose $H$ is a subgroup of a group $G$ and $aH$ is a left coset. Prove that there exists some $K$ (a subgroup of $G$) , which $aH$ is equal to $Ka$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, quotient-group

> Suppose $H$ is a subgroup of a group $G$ and $aH$ is a left coset. Prove that there exists some $K$ (a subgroup of $G$) , which $aH$ is equal to $Ka$.

I've tried to show this statement,but I cant find exactly what is $K$.

Comment: If $aH = Ka$, what happens if you move the $a$ to one side?

Comment: It implies that aHa^-1=K which means that a should be in H

Comment: but we want to prove the existance of such K

Comment: First part yes. But why would that imply that $a\in H$?

Comment: You now have $K = aHa^{-1}$. There is nothing further to be done.

Answer (score 2):

$$aH=Ka\iff aHa^{-1}=K$$
Aldo, note that, by a *homomorphism* ($x\longmapsto axa^{-1}$ is an automorphism of $G$), the image of a subgroup of $G$ is a subgroup.